# AppKit not dynamically sensing the frontmost app

Tags: python, appkit

I'm using Appkit in Python to have the computer sense the frontmost app.  It will correctly sense the frontmost app at first but when I change the frontmost app and leave the terminal running, it will not update the new information.  For example, the following code will work:

```
from AppKit import NSWorkspace
active_app_name = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().frontmostApplication().localizedName()
```

But now suppose I make Chrome rather than Excel the frontmost app and run the following program on terminal.  Then after the terminal prints 'Chrome', I click on the app 'Excel', the terminal will continue to print 'Chrome' and it will never sense that Excel is the frontmost app.

```
from AppKit import NSWorkspace
while True:
    active_app_name = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().frontmostApplication().localizedName()
    print (active_app_name)
    if active_app_name == 'Microsoft Excel':
        pass
        # do stuff
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
```

I want AppKit to be able to sense the new frontmost app when I make changes to which the frontmost app is.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the active_app to dynamically update use this code:

```
active_app = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().activeApplication()
```

Comment: a brief explanation would help.